# perl compare strings with "=="

Tags: perl

In perl, one should compare two strings with "eq" or "ne" etc.

I am a little surprised the following code snippet will print "yes".

```
$str = "aJohn";
$x = substr($str, 1);
if ($x == "John") {
    print "yes\n";
}
```

My perl has version v5.18.4 on Ubuntu.

Is there a case where the "==" on two strings produce a different result from "eq"?
Thanks.

Comment: `$str eq "John";` ... `$str == "John";`

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`"foo" == "bar"` is true. `"foo" eq "bar"` is false.

The reason for this: `==` is *numeric* comparison. `"foo"` and `"bar"` are both numerically evaluate to `0` (like `"17foo"` evaluates numerically to `17`); since `0 == 0`, `"foo" == "bar"`. This is not normally the operation you are looking for.

Comment: Note that using `"foo"` or `"17foo"` in numeric context will produce a warning, if you have warnings enabled as you should.